# Nautilus suddenly looks different after a restart

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, icons

Nautilus now looks different, and I don't like it. Before I restarted, I installed a few things, so that could of caused it.

[image: screenshot]

(the buttons are outlined and my icon pack isn't working for the 16x icons on the sidebar panel, but the address bar should look like that because I am using tweak tool to make it look like that)

If it matters, I'm using gnome 3 desktop environment.

Comment: What did you install? Can you remember?

Answer (score 2):

You're using nautilus 3.6. Chances are you added the [gnome3 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3), which has this version of nautilus.
You should check if your icon pack has an upgrade for nautilus 3.6, or you can [purge](http://bigbrovar.aoizora.org/index.php/2010/01/10/how-to-safely-remove-ppa-repository-from-ubuntu/) the gnome3 ppa.

If you have installed the gnome3 PPA, these are commands to restore old Nautilus:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Comment: `ppa-purge` automatically downgrades all packages in a given PPA back to the ubuntu versions.